# Aggregate array occourances

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I have a set of documents (*posts*) which have an array of users mentioned in each post.

```
{
    "title": "Some post title",
    [ ... ]
    "mentions": ["johnsmith", "johndoe", "paul"]
}
```

I want to aggregate a list of unique mentions, and the number of times they've been mentioned across all posts. For example:

```
[{ user: "johnsmith", count: 5 }, { user: "benlewis", count: 9 }, { user: "johndoe", count: 1 }]
```

With Mongo, I'd do something like:

```
"mentions": [{
    "$unwind": "$mentions"
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$mentions",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
   }
}]
```

What's the equivalent in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) aggregation for that. A small (5.x) example:

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "test" : {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "mentions": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/test/1
{
  "title": "Some post title",
  "mentions": [
    "johnsmith",
    "johndoe",
    "paul"
  ]
}

POST test/test/2
{
  "title": "Some post title 2",
  "mentions": [
    "johnsmith"
  ]
}

GET test/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "test": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "mentions",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Gives the following response:

```
"aggregations": {
    "test": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "johnsmith",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "johndoe",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "paul",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps :)